# How to resolve "Using deprecated Layout Route format" error with expo-router in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm working on a React Native app using Expo and I've recently integrated `expo-router` for routing. My app's file structure is set up to have dynamic routes for groups, and it works correctly until I add an edit page with a dynamic URL segment.

Here's the directory structure of my app:

[image: folder structure]

Everything works until I introduce the `edit.tsx` file inside the `[uniqueURL]` folder. When I try to navigate to the edit page, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Using deprecated Layout Route format: Move `./app/group/[uniqueURL].tsx` to `./app/group/[uniqueURL]/_layout.tsx`

// followed by the error stack trace
```

Here's the relevant part of my `_layout.tsx` component:

```
// ... other imports
function RootLayoutNav() {
  // ... other code
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      {/* ... other code */}
      <Stack>
        {/* ... other stack screens */}
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="group/[uniqueURL]" 
          options={{
            header: () => <CustomHeader />,
          }} />
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="group/[uniqueURL]/edit" 
          options={{
            header: () => <CustomHeader />,
          }} />
      </Stack>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Also i have tried the method it recommended I use and moved the `[uniqueURL].tsx` to `[uniqueURL]/_layout.tsx` and still get an error.

```
[Layout children]: No route named "group/[uniqueURL]/edit" exists in nested children: ["creategroup", "forgotpassword", "group/[uniqueURL]", "index", "login", "signup", "_sitemap", "[...404]"]
```

Could someone please advise me on how to fix this error? I want to keep the edit page nested within the [uniqueURL] directory as it fits the organization of my app's routes.

Comment: Have you read the complete message? It's telling you exactly how to fix the issue.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i already tried that and did not work, i updated the code showing that i did exactly that and the error i get.

Comment: You have the wrong path, please, check it

Answer (score 1):

When you moved `[uniqueURL].tsx` to `[uniqueURL]/_layout.tsx`, it was the correct step, but it seems there's still an issue with how the nested routes are being handled.

You should ensure that the directory structure looks like this:

```
app/
└── group/
    ├── [uniqueURL]/
    │   ├── edit.tsx
    │   └── _layout.tsx
    └── ...
```

In your `[uniqueURL]/_layout.tsx`, you need to define the nested route for `edit.tsx`. Your `_layout.tsx` inside `[uniqueURL]` directory might look something like this:

```
import { Outlet } from 'expo-router';

function UniqueURLLayout() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      {/* ... other code */}
      <Stack>
        {/* ... other stack screens */}
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="edit"  // Note the change here
          component={EditScreen} // Assuming EditScreen is the component for edit.tsx
          options={{ header: () => <CustomHeader /> }} 
        />
      </Stack>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default UniqueURLLayout;
```

The `RootLayoutNav` in your root `_layout.tsx` doesn't need to explicitly define the `group/[uniqueURL]/edit` route since it's now handled by the `[uniqueURL]/_layout.tsx`.

Make sure that the names you use in `Stack.Screen` match the names of the files, or the route names you want to define.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what about the index.js as the `group/[uniqueURL].js` was supposed to ba a page on its own that people can see details about a group. where is the code for that page supposed to go?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue can be resolved by changing the folder structure to
[something like this][1]
and then adding the functionalities in `[uniqueURL].tsx` in the `[uniqueURL]/index.js` file:

[image: 2]

Comment: You should use typescript in your replica since OP is using typescript